# PowerPoint VBA How to set the color of msoAnimEffectChangeFillColor Effect

Tags: vba, powerpoint, effect

I am using PowerPoint 2010 and I am trying to add animation to a bunch of shapes that will change their color to green,
but all I get is that the color is changing to dark red

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim oshp As Shape
Dim oslide As Slide

Set oslide = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)

'Clear all animations
For i = 1 To oslide.TimeLine.MainSequence.Count
    oslide.TimeLine.MainSequence.Item(1).Delete
Next

For i = 1 To 4
    Set oshp = oslide.Shapes(i)
    ' Assign an animation to shape
    Set oEffect = oslide.TimeLine.MainSequence.AddEffect(Shape:=oshp, effectId:=msoAnimEffectChangeFillColor, trigger:=msoAnimTriggerAfterPrevious)
    oEffect.EffectParameters.Color2.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    oEffect.Timing.SmoothEnd = msoTrue
    oEffect.Timing.Duration = 0.2
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure it is not working? It showing green here.

Comment: Hi - I also wish to change a shape to green and have used the same commands. I can get the shape to change to any colour except green! So if I set the RGB to blue it comes out as blue etc. However, if I try for green the colour is the default colour set in powerpoint. I would appreciate any suggestions!